# How to return reference from BlueprintImplementableEvent?

Tags: reference, unreal-engine4

I've got a C++ component and I want to have function which will be implemented in Blueprint like this:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
Stats& GetStats();
```

But this doesn't compile, I get the following error:

> overload function differs only by return type from

and Unreal generates function inside .gen.cpp looking like this:

```
Stats Component::GetStats()
{
// ...
}
```

Stats is USTRUCT

Answer (score -1):

You need to use enum pattern of Unreal, not ordinary c++ pattern. like this:

```
UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum class Stats : uint8
{
    S1,
    S2,
};
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question at all. I've got USTRUCT9(declared in C++) which is created inside blueprint and I wanna get this instance(created in blueprint) in my C++ component

Comment: You'd better post your code of your USTRUCT. have you add GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY() in your USRUCT ? like this :

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FBPUserOnlineAccount
{
 GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

public:
}